# Counter resets during execution

Tags: java

I am developing a Paper Rock Spock...game. However the score counter keeps resetting throughout. Can someone shed some light on how I can fix this please? The playGame() method takes two random numbers and match them against known constants. Then it should increment the player1 or player2 score depending on the output of the logical statement.

```
public class PaperRockGame {

    private static final int SCISSOR = 1;
    private static final int LIZARD = 2;
    private static final int PAPER = 3;
    private static final int ROCK = 4;
    private static final int SPOCK= 5;
    private static final int PLAYER1 = 1;
    private static final int PLAYER2 = 2;
    private String cpuChoice1;
    private String cpuChoice2;
    private int player1Score;
    private int player2Score;
    private int lastWinner;
    //private int player2Score;


    public void setCpuOne() {
        String choice;
        choice = numberToString(randomNumber());
        cpuChoice1 = choice;    
    }

    public void setCpuTwo() {
        String choice;
        choice = numberToString(randomNumber());
        cpuChoice2 = choice;
    }

    public String getCpuOneValue() {
        return cpuChoice1;
    }

    public String getCpuTwoValue() {
        return cpuChoice2;
    }

    public int getP1Score() {
        return player1Score;
    }

    public int getP2Score() {
        return player2Score;
    }

    public int randomNumber() {
        int number = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1 );
        return number;
    }

    public String numberToString(int value) {
        int number = value;
        if (number == 1) {
            return "SCISSOR";
        }
        else if(number == 2) {
            return "LIZARD";
        }
        else if(number == 3) {
            return "PAPER";
        }
        else if(number == 4) {
            return "ROCK";
        }
        else { 
            return "SPOCK";
        }
    }

    public void playGame(int cpuOne, int cpuTwo) {
        if(cpuOne == cpuTwo) {
            System.out.println("Tie");
        }
        else if ((cpuOne ==  ROCK && ( cpuTwo == SCISSOR || cpuTwo ==  LIZARD))
            ||(cpuOne ==  SCISSOR && ( cpuTwo == PAPER || cpuTwo == LIZARD))
            ||(cpuOne ==  PAPER && ( cpuTwo == ROCK || cpuTwo == SPOCK))
            ||(cpuOne ==  LIZARD && ( cpuTwo == PAPER || cpuTwo == SPOCK))
            ||(cpuOne ==  SPOCK && ( cpuTwo == SCISSOR || cpuTwo == ROCK))){

            System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
            if(lastWinner == PLAYER1) {
                player1Score++;
            }
            else {
                player1Score = 1;
            } 
            lastWinner = PLAYER1;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
            if(lastWinner == PLAYER2) {
                player2Score++;
            }
            else {
                player2Score = 1;
            }
            lastWinner = PLAYER2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x = 0;
        PaperRockGame play = new PaperRockGame ();

        do {
            play.setCpuOne();
            play.setCpuTwo();
            System.out.println(play.getCpuOneValue());
            System.out.print(play.getCpuTwoValue());
            System.out.println();
            play.playGame(play.randomNumber(), play.randomNumber());
            System.out.println(play.getP1Score() + " " + play.getP2Score());
            x++;
        } while(x < 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the **lastWinner** *int* type variable. You just don't need it to carry out the required logic for score keeping. This then means that you can also get rid of any code that uses this variable.

Let's put it this way. If ***Player 1*** wins then simply increment the ***Player 1*** score. No one cares who won the previous game. The overall score at the end of all games will finally tell the tale. On the same token, if ***Player 2*** wins then simply increment the ***Player 2*** score. So.....

```
public void playGame(int cpuOne, int cpuTwo) {
    if(cpuOne == cpuTwo) {
        System.out.println("Tie");
    }
    else if ((cpuOne ==  ROCK && ( cpuTwo == SCISSOR || cpuTwo ==  LIZARD))
        ||(cpuOne ==  SCISSOR && ( cpuTwo == PAPER || cpuTwo == LIZARD))
        ||(cpuOne ==  PAPER && ( cpuTwo == ROCK || cpuTwo == SPOCK))
        ||(cpuOne ==  LIZARD && ( cpuTwo == PAPER || cpuTwo == SPOCK))
        ||(cpuOne ==  SPOCK && ( cpuTwo == SCISSOR || cpuTwo == ROCK))){

        System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
        player1Score++;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
        player2Score++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the current winner differs from the last winner, you are resetting the score for that player to one.

<strike>I think instead you should initialize `player1Score` and `player2Score` to 0.</strike>

```
private int player1Score=0;
private int player2Score=0;
```

The default value of a primitive int in Java is 0. You can simply increment it.

Then simply remove the `if(lastWinner...` conditional and always do either `player1Score++` or `player2Score++`.